# Fundamental theorem of Algebra from the Brouwer fixed point theorem.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, polynomials, algebraic-topology

Here is my attempt to prove the Fundamental theorem of algebra from the Brouwer fixed point theorem.

**Lemma** (*Brouwer fixed point theorem*). If $f:D_r\rightarrow D_r$ is a continous function, then there is a point $z_0 \in D_r$ such that $f(z_0)=z_0$.

**Theorem** (*Fundamental theorem of algebra*). Every non-constant complex polynomial $$p(z)=a_n z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1 z+a_0,$$ where $a_0 \neq 0$, vanish somewhere in $\mathbb{C}$.

*Proof*:
If the polynomial $p$ doesn't vanish in $\mathbb{C}$, then for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$ we have the following

$$g(z)=\frac{-a_0}{a_n z^{n-1}+a_{n-1}z^{n-2}+...+a_1}\neq z.$$

If $g$ **is not** continuous, then the polynimial $a_n z^{n-1}+a_{n-1}z^{n-2}+...+a_1$ must vanish somewhere in $\mathbb{C}$, and we are done since $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary.

Suppose that $g$ **is** continuous. Now $g$ has the growth condition $|g(z)|\rightarrow 0$ as $|z|\rightarrow \infty$, so there is a constant $R>0$ such that $g(z)\in D_R$ when $z\in D_R$. Due to the Brouwer fixed point theorem $g$ can't be continuous since $g(z)\neq z$ in $D_R$. Again we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error relates to your claim
$$g(z)=\frac{-a_0}{a_n z^{n-1}+a_{n-1}z^{n-2}+\cdots +a_1}\neq z.$$

> "If $g$ is **not** continuous, then the polynomial $a_n z^{n-1}+a_{n-1}z^{n-2}+\cdots +a_1$ must vanish somewhere in $\mathbb{C}$, and we are done since $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary."

More specifically, your error is the fragment

> " . . . and we are done since $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary."

What you actually proved is that at least one of the polynomials
$$a_n z^{n-1}+a_{n-1}z^{n-2}+\cdots +a_1$$
$$a_n z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1 z+a_0$$
has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But I checked both cases: $g$ is continuous and $g$ is not?

Comment: If $g$ is not continuous, then the denominator has a zero. But that's a new polynomial, not the original one.

Comment: My aim was to show that if a general n. degree polynomial doesn't vanish, then a general (n-1). degree polynomial do vanish. So apparently that's not enough?

Comment: The goal is to show that every $n$-th degree polynomial $p(z)$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$, Once you choose it, it's no longer free. Let $q(z)$ be the denominator of $g(z)$, The polynomial $q(z)$ depends on $p(z)$, so it's also not free.

Comment: Thus, what you proved is: Given an $n$-th degree polynomial $p(z)$, the associated polynomial $q(z)$ is such that at least one of $p(z),q(z)$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What if we cinsider the function $$\frac{z}{|p(z)|+1}:D_R \rightarrow D_R.$$ It is continuous and has a fixed point. Therefore $|p(z_0)|=0$.

Comment: Sure it has a fixed point, for example $z=0$. How do you know it has a _nonzero_ fixed point? But good try (+1) (but I already gave you).

Comment: Oops! Now I drop this topic. Thanks for answering!